# hls.js hls.subtitleTracks returns empty array

Tags: javascript, m3u8, hls.js

Here is my m3u8 master file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="English",URI="subtitle.m3u8",LANGUAGE="en"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=500000,RESOLUTION=1920x1080,SUBTITLES="subs"
index.m3u8
```

The video loads correctly using hlsjs. Here is my javascript:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var videoSrc = './video/master.m3u8';
if (Hls.isSupported()) {
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource(videoSrc);
    hls.attachMedia(video);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function(event, data) {
        console.log(hls.subtitleTracks);
        video.play();
    });  
}
```

But console.log returns an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: @Jonny see this [issue on github](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/2796)

Comment: I think I figured this out actually. We are supposed to add an event listener to the `player.textTracks` array, not the player itself. I think the name of the event was "trackAdded" or something similar. Then it seems to be work for both Chromeish browsers and Safari. Also this description seems old and outdated, but can partly be followed with a few fixes https://videojs.com/guides/text-tracks/#working-with-text-tracks for instance I think it's `player.textTracks`, not `player.textTracks()` with parantheses.